# With one click, I try to change a certain object using an index, which, however, does not result

Tags: reactjs

In a map function I try to pass an index to a component function, which, when I click on the respective line, is passed to a function, which then changes the object. The problem is that when I click on the row, this index won't score

```
export default function Kalender() {
const [mitarbeiter, setMitarbeiter] = React.useState(null);

const mit = [
{
  vorname: "Max",
  nachname: "Müller",
  checked: false,
},
{
  vorname: "Sabine",
  nachname: "Groß",
  checked: false,
},

];

[...]



/* HERE THE INDEX IS NULL/UNDEFINDED*/
 function checkMit(index) {

 const newArray = [...mitarbeiter];
 newArray[index].checked = true;
 setMitarbeiter(newArray);    
 }


function Mitarbeiter(mitarbeiter, index) {
 return (
  <div
    style={{ background: mitarbeiter.checked ? "green" : "" }}
    onClick={() => checkMit(index)}
  >
    <h5>{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiter.vorname}</h5>
    <h6>{mitarbeiter.mitarbeiter.nachname}</h6>
    <hr></hr>
  </div>
 );
}

return (
<>
  {mitarbeiter.map((element, index) => (
    <Mitarbeiter
      key={index}
      mitarbeiter={element}
      index={index}
    ></Mitarbeiter>
  ))}
 </>
 );
}
```

Comment: You are passing `index` as a prop to `Mitarbeiter` component so you need to destructure `index` from the props object ---> `({ mitarbeiter, index })`

Comment: Very stupid of me ... thank you four times: D